# Can't Import <msxml6.dll>, Cannot Open .tlh File

Tags: c++, xml, msxml6

On Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012 I am trying:

```
#include "msxml6.h"
#import <msxml6.dll>rename_namespace(_T("MSXML"))
```

And getting the error:

> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "D:/Poses-master/Poses-master/msxml6.tlh"

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: But does it *build*?

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't even need `#include "msxml6.h"` with that important statement, which will slurp in the comdef-wrapper straight ffrom the type libraries in msxml6.dll

Comment: @Sun Note that Intelisense errors are not real errors, they do not prevent building or running. If this does not *run* or *build* find your first non-Intelisense error and post that instead.

Comment: problem solved, you are all right.  thank you guys !